How to get X-Virtual-mta details from Mailkit SMTP /MTA
Recent we have started adding X-Virtual-mta as header while sending email using Mailkit.net.smtp client.
I have few question on this, like can value of this Header key be retrieved while we are using Mailkit.Net.smtp.SmtpClient() in the C# ?
Do we need to configure SMTP client or any of its MTA so that it can know about X-Virtual-mta value?
If SMTP client is entirely not configured, how this can be configured?
My currently knowledge about MTA or SMTP is limited but I will appreciate any help on this question?
Expecting some help on this question.
